# How to pause a loop print in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, pause

I have the following code:

```python
i = 0
numbers = []

while i < 6:
    print ("At the top i is %d" % i)
    numbers.append(i)

    i = i + 1
    print ("Numbers now: ", numbers)
    print ("At the bottom i is %d" % i)


print ("The numbers: ")

for num in numbers:
    print (num)
```

If I import `sleep` it will slow it down, but how can I pause it so it proceeds when I want it to?

Comment: Hi. Please note the minor copy edits and formatting I made to your question. It’s not good to start a question with a code snippet. You need to start your question with either the question itself, or some kind of in brief introduction at least. Also, you should use a `<!-- language: lang-python -->` comment to make sure the code gets syntax-highlighted correctly. (And welcome to StackOverflow, by the way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `input()` where you want it to pause.

```
i=0
numbers = []
while i < 6:
    print("At the top i is %d" % i)
    numbers.append(i)

    i = i + 1
    print("Numbers now: ", numbers)
    print("At the bottom i is %d" % i)
    input() # add it here for example.


print("The numbers: ")

for num in numbers:
    print(num)
```